# Main breaker and branch breaker tripped simultaneously

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I live in a high rise apartment built in the '70s (USA), and this afternoon we suddenly lost all power to just our unit. After some investigation we found that the main disconnect (70A) powering our unit had tripped. When I looked into our own load center, the oven/range breaker (50A) was also tripped.

We weren't doing anything unusual - the oven was on and some lights, but we've often had the dishwasher/lights/hair dryers/etc. running simultaneously. I find it strange that both the 50A and the 70A tripped simultaneously. Does anyone know why this can happen?

If it's relevant, I have installed some LED light bulbs into dimmers that are not for LEDs (on different circuits from the oven/range circuit) and some of them were on at the time. Doesn't seem like that should be relevant but it's the only thing I can think of.

UPDATE - found the root cause! It turns out the range and the cooktop were combined together in a box in the cupboard with wire nuts and then a single line was run to the 50A breaker. Wires in one of the connections melted the plastic and shorted, tripping the breaker.

Currently we have only the cooktop connected, as there's significant work required to bring the unit up to the current code (last remodel was 10 years ago). They'll have to move the panel outside of the closet and increase the size as all the current spaces are doubled up.

Photo of the carnage - thank you to the poster who told me to keep the breaker shut off!
[image]

Comment: 50A and 70A are amperage rating? It's seems kinda insane to have such a high amperage at a flat. In Czech Republic we have usually 16-25A depeding if you have electric water heater or not...

Comment: @jnovacho Those numbers are perfectly normal for the US, where everything is on half the voltage (120V, thus twice as much current for the same power) and only split-phase system (thus just two legs 240V apart, not three phases with 400V between them). A 3x16 A feed for an electric range would be standard in Europe, and that's basically the equivalent of a 50A 240V breaker in the US. So, nothing insane here.

Comment: @jnovacho wait until you see a 200A disconnect.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Very simple: Massive power overload from the oven.

The 70A and 50A tripping at the same time means:

- Problem is past the 50A. Since that has just one appliance, we know the source of the overload.
- Since 70A tripped, must be greater than 70A, which of course is also greater than 50A.
- Since breakers are generally designed with a thermal trip curve to avoid trips from motor startup and similar short surges, this was likely far more than 70A, because if it was 71A it would trip the 50A quickly but not the 70A.

My guess is an element (oven or cooktop) failed but short circuited along the way, tripping the breakers.

I'd be extremely wary of turning on the 50A (the 70A is fine) without getting the oven checked by a professional first. If you're in a rental, call the landlord.

Comment: Yup. When a calrod element fails, consider yourself lucky that it failed hard enough to trip the breaker. I've had an oven element make a loud pop and proceed to arc in a messy and dramatic way *without* tripping the breaker. I was *really* happy that I was there in the kitchen to hear the funny noise and look though the oven window at a molten mess in progress so I could shut the oven off. 50A will support quite a bit of pyrotechnics before it trips.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  And it can really screw up the oven shell.

Comment: Yikes!  And they say cooking with natural gas is dangerous.   I learn stuff every time I come here.  BTW, I have a gas range!

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson I don't think this makes electric more dangerous than gas. I'd much rather have my range catch fire than my whole house explode.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Electric and gas each have their own rare but serious problems. For electric, it is an element or other failure causing arcing/melting/fire. For gas, there are two very different problems: fire and explosion. Fire if something spills or otherwise gets into the flame that shouldn't - this can happen with electric too, but I'd argue much easier with gas. Explosion is an entirely different problem - that happens if you have an actual pipe leaking gas (very rare) or a burner "on" but not ignited **and** gas leaks for a relatively long time and **then**...

Comment: has a source of ignition (open flame or sparks from something) and then **KABOOM**. Fortunately, that is all relatively rare as well.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact  Agreed. My comment was a bit tongue in cheek, but I didn't know electrical elements could short out like that.   And yes, it's easier to catch something on fire with gas range top than electric by far (I've had to throw away a couple of pot holders and towels due to that!).

Comment: The issue, as with many things, is whether a device is designed to "fail safe". (That's not "fail-safe", which is different.) For example, you want your circuit breakers designed in a way that they can "fail by tripping too soon" rather than "fail by tripping too late" (or worse, not at all). But no engineering design is perfect/covers every possible failure mode, which is why we have layers of protection.

Comment: Breakers also have a time to trip specification. A 50 A breaker running 51 A might take over an hour to trip, but at 100 A it'll trip in a second. Typically a ground short will blow the fuse fairly quickly due to unlimited current going through the circuit, but anything with a load will change that. I've seen malfunctioning air conditioners that will take 45 minutes to trip because the current is leaking out slowly.

Comment: Landlords are going to send an electrician out to see what the problem is - will let everyone know if this was the issue and mark as answered depending on what they say. Thank you!

Comment: 50A sounds massive for an oven to me. Is that an industrial type? Around here, most ovens are single-phase and below 16A. Granted, that's on 230V, but that's one of the reasons we're on 230V: keeps the shorting currents lower because everything only requires half as much. To your standards that would be about 35A equivalent, so how is 50 even a thing?

Comment: @Mast 50A is not that unusual. With a quick search for an oven similar to mine (double oven, self-cleaning, convection in one oven), I found 40A @ 240V.

Comment: @Mast "Oven" here usually means a range with a cooktop plus an oven.  40A and 50A are typical breaker sizes.  50A @ 240V supplies 12kW, so if you have four cooktop elements, each with an average of even only 1500W that's 6kW already that you need to support, *plus* the oven, a fan, broiler, warming zone, a convenience outlet (15A@120V) and 12kW is a perfectly reasonable breaker size.

Comment: @J... You're right - the example here is "oven/range", which typically means oven + cooktop. My double-oven (and I think most) is designed so it effectively balances the load and won't allow the extremes - e.g., can't run self-clean on both ovens at the same time. But oven + cooktop can really use a lot of power at once because the cooktop elements are independent of the oven controls.

Comment: @Ecnerwal a good GFCI protection solves most of these firework-like failure modes.

Comment: @topher sounds like you've got your answer. Please give this one a check mark (for recommending calling the landlord), or make sure you post the actual issue after the electricians check things out and give yourself a check mark (perfectly acceptable and expected).